# Bookmarks disappeared after windows install

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

After I installed my Windows 10 my bookmarks from Google Chrome disappeared.

How can I recover them?

Answer (score 1):

If your bookmarks are synced with your Google account, which they are by default if you logged into a Google account in Chrome, all you have to do is login again. Go to the three dots at the top, choose "Settings" and you will see an option to log in at the top.

If you did not sync your bookmarks with Google, or in any other way, and did not back up your bookmarks in another way, I'm sorry to say they are gone.

There's no better way to learn the value of backups than data loss. Sorry.